# MySqli prepared statement with $_POST from XMLHttpRequest isn't working

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I'm trying to get a simple mysqli prepared statement to work. I'm running this script using an XMLHttpRequest.

On the website I'm working on you'll be able to give a bunch of inputs and I need to sanitize everything. Since `mysqli_real_escape_string` is not sufficient I have to use prepared statements.

This is the query without prepared statement:

```
$account = $_POST["passaccountname"];
$newFullName = $_POST["userNameUpdate"];

$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'os_test');
$sql = $mysqli->query("UPDATE test_users SET FULLNAME='".$newFullName."' WHERE LOWER(REPLACE(NAME, ' ', ''))='".$account."'");
```

This worked perfectly but of course this is not secure!

So I looked into how to make a prepared statement and it didn't look to hard. I changed the `passaccountname` variable around and match it to the 'NAME' column/row.

Even though on the surface it seemed simple nothing seems to happen, this is the code now:

```
$account = $_POST["passaccountname"];
$newFullName = $_POST["userNameUpdate"];

$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'os_test');
$sql = $mysqli->query("UPDATE test_users SET FULLNAME=? WHERE NAME=?");
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $n, $a);

$n = $newFullName;
$a = $account;
$stmt->execute();
```

Is there something wrong with my code? I really do not understand what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: Remove query() call.

Comment: Well change the `->query()` line to `$sql = "UPDATE test_users SET FULLNAME=? WHERE NAME=?";` would be better @Dharman

Comment: `$sql = "UPDATE test_users SET FULLNAME=? WHERE NAME=?"; $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);` Also note you should have `LOWER(REPLACE(NAME, ' ', '')) = ?` to match your existing query

Comment: Why don't you just bind to the existing variables - `$stmt->bind_param("ss", $newFullName, $account);` rather than create new ones.

Comment: @Dharman bet you're wishing you'd answered instead of commenting!

Comment: @NigelRen Oh, that's a good point. Thanks.

Comment: @nick Sometimes I can't judge whether it should be closed as typo or answered. Plus I should actually be working, not wasting time on SO.

Comment: @Dharman well I voted for typo... but I just can't see how you could call time on SO wasted!!!! :-)

Comment: The oddest thing is 2 people upvoted the question :(

Comment: @RiggsFolly I'm pretty sure the `Suffrage` and `Vox Populi` badges are the cause of a lot of such votes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're almost there.

Currently you're trying to *execute* this query instead of *prepare* it:

```
$sql = $mysqli->query("UPDATE test_users SET FULLNAME=? WHERE NAME=?");
```

Remove the call to `query()`.  You could just replace that line with:

```
$sql = "UPDATE test_users SET FULLNAME=? WHERE NAME=?";
```

Since you pass that variable to `prepare()` on the next line.

---

**Edit:** In response to [a comment below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59267298/mysqli-prepared-statement-with-post-from-xmlhttprequest-dont-wroking/59267370?noredirect=1#comment104742206_59267370), it's also generally a good idea to [enable mysqli exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14578243/turning-query-errors-to-exceptions-in-mysqli) in your code.  By default errors like this one "fail silently", which can make them difficult to catch.  (This was likely just for backward compatability with previous mysql/mysqli error checking.)

By enabling these exceptions, these errors are more visibly reported and easier to find.

Comment: crazy how I didn't see that.. thanks a lot, it works now!

Comment: I would also recommend to enable MySQLi exceptions, because such mistakes would not be reported otherwise.

Comment: I'm only using notepad++

Comment: @Miger: I don't see what you're getting at in your last comment.  While it's recommended to use a full IDE, any text editor is technically fine for editing code.  But surely at some point you're *running* this code, which is where/when the error takes place?

Comment: I'm testing everything with XAMPP and while I'm sorry that this question was therefore quite unnecessary, such typos don't happen very often to me and usually I find them myself. I've never used mysqli before and also php is only now getting a little more familiar. I'm sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: @Miger: No need to be sorry :)  I just wanted to make sure you're not still experiencing an issue with the code.  It looks like this question was a bit on the fence in the overall Stack Overflow debate of "answering or voting to close".  Admittedly I thought about it a moment, but decided to answer.  Others decided to vote to close.  I don't think either course of action was incorrect, and as long as you got your answer then either way the exchange was successful.  Battling for reputation points is a lesser concern than helping the community :)